# how to set opacity of background image without affecting text

Tags: android, button, text, opacity

I am setting the opacity of image I am using as background in button. But when I set opacity of button its also changing the opacity of text. I try with setting button text programmatically. But still not working. How to set opacity without affecting text color opacity?

Code-

```
hist = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hist);
hist.setText("HISTORY");
```

Xml-

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/hist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bttn"
        android:alpha=".6"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="@dimen/btxt"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to change the alpha on the image (bttn), not on the Button itself.

Comment: In many ways. If it's a png, use a graphical editor. If it's an xml drawable, it should have an android:alpha attribute. Or do it via code, as @Deacoy shows in his answer (will work on both images and xml drawables)

Comment: @KlingKlang How to change the transparency of button without it affecting the transparency of button text? I set the button:alpha as 0.25 but it is also affecting button text color. How to prevent this behavior?

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria `button:alpha` affects the whole object. You want to draw only the background. Therefore, prepare a 0.25 alpha image or drawable and assign it to the button background. Just as simple as this.

Comment: @KlingKlang I followed the answer below and that worked, via Java code, it doesn't affect text color.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria That's because `xyz.getBackground().setAlpha(someValue);` afttects the background of xyz.

Answer (score 2):

From code:

```
yourButton.getBackground().setAlpha(100);
```

Comment: I dont have any textView. How to do this with text on a button?